# How can make my makefile overwrite a file?

Tags: c++, linux

```
descript: progam.cpp
    g++ progam.cpp -o descript
    ./descript 2>output.txt | tee -a output.txt
```

From my understanding, first command compiles program.cpp and the second command sends the output to both terminal and a textfile.

Is there a way to adjust this so that I :

- Use "make".Go through program prompts. Output is saved in output.txt
- Use "./descript" or some command a second time and overwrite output.txt with new output

I'm fairly new to linux commands in general so anything would help.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Nothing stops you from "Use "./descript" or some command a second time". If you want to automate that using make, you have to be more specific in so far as what you want to do, and when.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand fully what a make does. I thought if i ran the make,everytime i ran ./descript the commands under it would run right?

Comment: Whatever "./descript" is, it has nothing to do with `make`.

Comment: Really? oh wow. When i use "./descript" it runs the progam. I though it was related to the "descript: program.cpp" so when ever use "./descript" it would run everything under "descript: program.cpp"

Comment: No. "./descript" runs the compiled program, "descript". You can build it from "progam.cpp" without using make, just fine. "make" is nothing more than an automated means to execute commands based on files and timestamps. Go read "make"'s manual page.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll look into the manual.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It may be helpful to include a `make clean` function in your `Makefile`.

Example `make clean` function could include:

```
make clean:
    rm -f output.txt
```

Then, insert the `make clean` at the beginning of your `descript` portion of the `Makefile` to auto-remove the previous output.

Comment: descript: progam.cpp
        g++ progam.cpp -o descript
        ./descript 2>output.txt | tee -a output.txt

Comment: So i tried using make clean and inserting it before ./descript. In both cases they did great in removing the previous output.txt but another one was not created. In both cases I ran the make and went through the program. Then when i was done i ran it agian with ./descript but a new output.txt did not appear

Comment: You should be doing a call to *make* the `descript` executable under `make :`, where you currently have `descript:`. 

make: progam.cpp     make clean
        g++ progam.cpp -o descript
        ./descript 2>output.txt | tee -a output.txt

Comment: Oh I get it! Thank you!